# Objeto nulo na View

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

O pedido:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="wp_posts")
public class Pedido implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(name="post_status")
private String status;

@Column(name="post_type")
private String tipo;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pedido", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)  
private List<PedidoMeta> pedidoMeta;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pedido", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<PedidoItem> itens;

@Column(name="post_date")
private Date data;

@Transient
private Usuario cliente;
```

O Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/detalhePedido/{id}")
public ModelAndView detalhePedido( @PathVariable(value = "id", required = false) String pedidoid) {

    pedido = pedidoRepository.findOne(new Long(pedidoid));
    pedido = pedidoService.findCliente(pedido);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("DetalhePedido");
    modelAndView.addObject("pedido",pedido);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

a View:

```
<tbody>
  <tr th:object="${pedido}">
   <td th:text="*{pedido.id}"></td>
   <td th:text="*{pedido.cliente.nome}"></td>
   <td th:text="*{#dates.format(pedido.data, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}"></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

O erro:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: 
Property or field 'pedido' cannot be found on object of type 'com.ledolate.sys.model.Pedido' - maybe not public?
```

Ao debugar, o pedido esta correto, com todas as informações, mas, ao chegar na camada de visualização apresenta este erro.